# Selecting the best-performing sales rep by date

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, max, aggregate-functions

Given two tables, `sales_reps` and `sales`:

```
sales_reps
+--------+-------+
| rep_id | name  |
+--------+-------+
| 1      | Tony  |
+--------+-------+
| 2      | Jim   |
+--------+-------+
| 3      | Laura |
+--------+-------+
| 4      | Sam   |
+--------+-------+

sales
+------------+----------+--------+-------------+
|  sale_date | sales_id | rep_id | sale_amount |
+------------+----------+--------+-------------+
| 2021-01-01 | 1        | 1      | 2000        |
+------------+----------+--------+-------------+
| 2021-01-01 | 2        | 1      | 4000        |
+------------+----------+--------+-------------+
| 2021-01-01 | 3        | 2      | 3000        |
+------------+----------+--------+-------------+
| 2021-01-01 | 4        | 1      | 1000        |
+------------+----------+--------+-------------+
| 2021-01-01 | 5        | 4      | 5000        |
+------------+----------+--------+-------------+
| 2021-01-02 | 6        | 3      | 10000       |
+------------+----------+--------+-------------+
| 2021-01-02 | 7        | 3      | 10000       |
+------------+----------+--------+-------------+
| 2021-01-02 | 8        | 2      | 4000        |
+------------+----------+--------+-------------+
| 2021-01-02 | 9        | 1      | 6000        |
+------------+----------+--------+-------------+
| 2021-01-02 | 10       | 4      | 2000        |
+------------+----------+--------+-------------+
| 2021-01-03 | 11       | 2      | 8000        |
+------------+----------+--------+-------------+
| 2021-01-03 | 12       | 2      | 1000        |
+------------+----------+--------+-------------+
| 2021-01-03 | 13       | 3      | 4500        |
+------------+----------+--------+-------------+
| 2021-01-03 | 14       | 3      | 4500        |
+------------+----------+--------+-------------+
```

I want to show how many unique reps made sales by date (easy) and the `rep_id` and `name` of the rep who generated the highest total sales amount for each date. If more than one rep generated the same greatest total sales amount for a date, I want to show the lesser `rep_id` and that rep's `name`. The results should look like this:

```
+------------+-------------+----------+----------+
|  sale_date | unique_reps | best_rep | rep_name |
+------------+-------------+----------+----------+
| 2021-01-01 | 3           | 1        |     Tony |
+------------+-------------+----------+----------+
| 2021-01-02 | 4           | 3        |    Laura |
+------------+-------------+----------+----------+
| 2021-01-03 | 2           | 2        |      Jim |
+------------+-------------+----------+----------+
```

Laura and Jim both generated $9,000 in sales on 2021-01-03. But Jim's `rep_id` is 2, which is less than Laura's `rep_id` of 3. So Jim is displayed as the rep who generated the greatest sales amount on 2021-01-03.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgres has a `mode()` function, but it doesn't allow you to choose *which* rep to choose in the case of ties.  For that, you can be more explicit:

```
select distinct on (s.sale_date) s.sale_date,
       s.rep_id, sr.name,
       count(*) over (partition by s.date) as num_reps
from sales s join
     sales_reps sr
     on s.rep_id = sr.rep_id
group by s.sale_date, s.rep_id
order by s.sale_date, sum(s.sale_amount) desc, s.rep_id, sr.name;
```

What is this doing?  It is aggregating by the date and sales rep.  Because of the `distinct on`, though, it is only taking one row per date.  In this row:

- `count(*) over (partition by date)` counts the number of reps (it is counting the rows *after* the aggregation).
- `s.rep_id` is chosen based on the `order by` criteria -- first the most sales, then by the lowest rep id.
- `sr.name` is the name of the sales rep.

Comment: This is great! I had seen `mode()` before, but I wasn't sure what to do in the case of showing an id based on a sum they're responsible for. Very helpful.